# Secondary axes in Excel for the same data series

Tags: excel, axis

I have a few dozen data points with an ordinary x and y axis. Now I want to have a secondary x axis for this data set.
That's how I'd like it: bottom (normal) x-axis being the "Time", the y-axis being the "Magnitude", and the top x-axis being the "Air". Attention, the Magnitude values are reversed - this is wanted.
Thank you very much for telling me how this works! 
Here's the dropbox link
https://www.dropbox.com/s/dd94769ehg1rq6m/worksheetSecondaryAxis.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: I've never used VBA and don't know what this is.

Comment: So you suggest Super User can solve my problem. Is SU a group here in stackoverflow or a member?

Comment: Ok, and where do I find the VBA for Excel? I don't see it in the menu bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I'm understanding your question correctly, but here goes. To plot the second set of data using the same y-axis and a secondary x-axis, follow these steps in Excel 2010:
1. Add the 2nd data series to the plot, e.g.
    =SERIES(,Tabelle1!$D$6:$D$45,Tabelle1!$B$6:$B$45,2)
It will not be visible because it falls outside of your fixed x-scale.
2. Select the 2nd data series. You can do this by clicking on the 1st data series and then using the up-arrow to get to the next data series.
3. The left-most part of the ribbon should now show Series 2. Below that click the Format Selection button to open the Format Data Series dialog
4. Choose the Plot Series on Secondary Axis option
5. In the ribbon choose Chart Tools | Layout | Axes | Secondary Horizontal Axis | More Secondary Horizontal Axis Options
6. Choose appropriate values for min and max (say 1.0 and 1.6 for your data).
7. Select the secondary Y-axis (on the right of the graph). Format the Horizontal axis to cross at the max value (-13.18 in my case).
8. In the ribbon choose Chart Tools | Layout | Axes | Secondary Vertical Axis | None to hide the second y-axis.
9. Select any other formatting options you want for the 2nd x-axis
Hope this helps --- here's my result
[image]

Comment: One more question: how can I link the primary axis together with the secondary axis? Short explanation: I only need one of the above data series, but with two x axes. If you reverse the secondary y-axis and also the secondary x-axis, you will see that the red data points are the same as the blue ones...just shifted and squeezed. I could adjust the axes limits like you explain, but this would be on an eye-basis and not really exact. The data series must match each other perfectly. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Lucas, when I reverse the red series in x and y, then shift/squeeze to make the minimum and maximum x-values match, the points in the middle don't match. To me it looks like your air and time data series are NOT linearly related, so simply reversing the axes won't work. If you have (or can estimate) an equation for air vs time, you could calculate a new data series Air_Calc, then plot and format Air_Calc to look like a secondary axis.

Comment: Hi xidgel. Non-linearity seems to be the obstacle yes. Your solution suggestion was a bit fast. Plotting an equation air vs. time can easily be displayed by Excel. So you suggest that taking the equation from air vs. time, feeding it with the magnitude could give a new data series with linear scale compared to the air vs. time. Plotting the second one as secondary would match both data series and quasi-link the axes through the used equation. Is that the outline of your solution?

Comment: This helps really! Albeit, there can be no space above/below the data series for the two linked, parallel axes, because there is no data that can be used to extend. The data series ranges very much from edge to edge. But that's as good as it gets. Thanks!